# Как создать рамку с изогнутыми краями при пересечении двух блоков

Tags: css

Подскажите как создать рамку такого типа https://www.screencast.com/t/3X6U5BeBQ6

Я пробовал создать что-то подобное https://jsfiddle.net/xy7m8ko4/2/ но не могу найти варианта с переходом left блока в right.

```
  <div class="block-wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="title">Création de site e-commerce à Nantes</div>
  </div><div class="right"></div>
  <div class="content">Doter votre commerce en ligne de solutions performantes est un impératif pour vous démarquer de vos concurrents. Cela passe par le déploiement des outils adéquats pour le fonctionnement de votre site web</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.title {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F9B700;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 7px 5px;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  width: 40%;
}

.right {
  width: 60%;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть надо доработать ...

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #fbfbfb;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.nav {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.nav a div {
  background: orange;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 40px;
  border-radius: 40%/4em;
  transform: translate(-5px, -5px);
}

.nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#">
      <div>elem1</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos voluptate velit optio ad id dolorum enim eos pariatur sit quas aliquam, minima maiores illum quasi sed dolorem, vitae ipsa iure earum fuga. Officiis, aut deserunt odit dolorum, harum in consectetur
    laboriosam quisquam qui ipsam itaque reiciendis magni! In, velit fugiat!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение спасибо!